# Office 365 Exchange EWS: "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again., The process failed to get the correct properties."

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

Trying to create an appointment into a shared mailbox using the following code:

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("user_id", "password");
service.AutodiscoverUrl(user_id, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback); //resolves to https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx

Appointment meeting1 = new Appointment(service);
            meeting1.Subject = "subject";
            meeting1.Body = "body";
            meeting1.Start = Convert.ToDateTime("some datetime");

            DateTime end = Convert.ToDateTime("some datetime");
            meeting1.End = end.AddMinutes(Convert.ToInt32("some number"));

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

Mailbox test = new Mailbox("some email");
FolderId folderid = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, test);
meeting1.Save(folderid,SendInvitationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy);
```

The error it returns is:

```
    Access is denied. Check credentials and try again., The process failed to get the correct properties.
```

I know the credentials are correct because the call to `AutodiscoverUrl` returned a valid URL. So im not sure why its saying "access is denied" when calling `save()`?

Comment: Exchange Online is deprecating Basic Authentication. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/announcements/exchange-online-basic-auth-deprecated I suggest you upgrade to Modern Authentication (based on OAuth 2.0)  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again, answering my own question.

The particular user being passed needed to be granted write permissions to the mailbox folder in question.